# Rest api testing using java POJO and jackson

Tags: java, rest, automated-tests, webservices-client

I am new to webservices testing and i am trying to test a webservice which returns both a JSON as well as XML output .

my management wants me to do this with jackson jersery and other libraries for XML

i created a java client using jersey and i got the response . i am not sure how to validate this response against a POJO class .

i am not entitled to use sophisticated  libraries like rest assured or json path . can some one explain me how will i validate/assert  both json and xml response against a POJO step by step and make my life easy ?
kindly help
also list down the libraries needed for handling xml responses too ?

Comment: If you are using Jersey framework to develop REST services then you can try Jersey Test Framework to test those services.

Answer (score 1):

[Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) is a new test-framework for testing web-services, and it supports both JSON and XML. You don't need to know Java and it does not need you to add any libraries.  The documentation is extensive and the [demo project](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo) has examples.

Disclaimer: am dev.

Comment: bro i have said i want to know only the pojo ...pls read my request

Comment: I did read your request. If I were you I would convince the management would try Karate because it reduces ALL the complexity you described. But if you really need to use "the pojo" - well, all the best :P